# Compare two column from CSV file using python

Tags: python, csv, logic

I have a CSV file like:

```
item1,item2 
A,B
B,C
C,D
E,F
```

I want to compare this two column and find the similar content from the two columns `item1` and `item2`. The output should be like this:

```
 item 
  B
  C
```

I have tried this code

```
with open('output/id.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)

for line in csvreader:
    if (line[0] == line[1]):
        print line
    else:
        print("not match")
```

I am new to programming. I don't know what the logic should be and how to solve this problem. please help.

Comment: There's an obvious `IndentationError` in your code; is that all you're asking about?

Comment: If not: What's wrong with the code you tried? Does it give the wrong output? Does it raise an exception? (If so, copy and paste it.) Does it seem to take way to long? Your code sample is perfect (except for that indentation problem, if that's not in your real code), but a [mcve] usually needs more than just the code.

Comment: I edited my coding part. now there is no IndentationError. 
the output shows "not match". which is not correct. @abarnert

Comment: Your first problem is that Python indexing is 0-based, not 1-based, so you're actually comparing the second and third columns, not the first and second. You want `if line[1] == line[0]:`.

Comment: But it's still not going to work, except to find cases where the matching values happen to be in the same row. (As [Jean-François Fabre already explained nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49667677/908494).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

1. Use `'\t'` as your delimiter, as your file is delimited by tabs, not commas
2. Get all the items from both lists as a set, then get the intersection of the two sets
3. Print them

Here's my implementation:

```
import csv
with open('output/id.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')

    items_in_1 = set()
    items_in_2 = set()

    for line in csvreader:
        items_in_1.add(line[0])
        items_in_2.add(line[1])

    items_in_both = items_in_1.intersection(items_in_2)

    print("item")
    for item in items_in_both:
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you use the `pandas` library, this will load your csv file into a nice dataframe data structure. Really convenient.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

Then you can get the similarities between both columns by doing

```
set(df['col1']) & set(df['col2'])
```

To get the output shaped the way you describe you can then make a new DataFrame with this intersected information as

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'item': list(set(df['col1']) & set(df['col2']))})
```

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 6, 4, 3], 'col2': [3, 2, 5, 6, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
set(df['col1']) & set(df['col2'])
```

> {2, 3, 6}

Answer (score 1):

You cannot succeed by reading row by rows. You have to work on the columns.

Read both columns of your csv file (without the title) into 2 python `set`s.

Perform sorted intersection and write back to another csv file:

```
import csv

with open("test.csv") as f:
    cr = csv.reader(f)
    next(cr) # skip title
    col1 = set()
    col2 = set()
    for a,b in cr:
        col1.add(a)
        col2.add(b)

with open("output.csv","w",newline="") as f:
    cw = csv.writer(f)
    cw.writerow(["item"])
    cw.writerows(sorted(col1 & col2))
```

with `test.csv` as:

```
item1,item2
A,B
B,C
C,D
E,F
```

you get

```
item
B
C
```

note: if your csv file has more than 2 columns, the unpack doesn't work properly, adapt like this:

```
for row in cr:
    col1.add(row[0])
    col2.add(row[1])
```

Comment: I am getting this error :for a,b in cr:
ValueError: too many values to unpack 
@Jean-François Fabre